# Filter list contains multiple objects java

Tags: java, java-stream

The code below works fine for me now, but it is not future proof, becuase the numbers of `if else` statments and `instanceof`. I would like to extend the Transport list with more objects like bicyles, motors etc.... but every time when I add new object I need to add more `if else` statements and create more `instanceof`. Does anyone have a better idea or better solution?

```
private static Transport filterObjects(List<Transport> listOfTransport, int refNr) {
    List<Transport> cars = listOfTransport.stream()
                                          .filter(transport -> transport instanceof Cars)
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    List<Transport> airPlanes = listOfTransport.stream()
                                               .filter(transport -> transport instanceof Airplanes)
                                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
   
    if (!cars.isEmpty()){
        return cars.get(refNr);
    } else if (!airPlanes.isEmpty()) {
       return airPlanes.get(refNr);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to decide in the future in which order you want to group your list and return priority?

Comment: minor optimisation: why not place those isNotEmpty and returns after the computation of respective `List`!

Comment: @Naman, how do you mean that? example?

Comment: @user3122166 Just don't compute `airPlanes` if you have got the `cars`, return right after that.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what exactly you are trying to achieve here, but you seem to be looking for *a single object* somehow related to the parameter `refNr`. Could you provide more details about what this method exactly should do?

Comment: How do you define `refNr` ? This smells like `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in the subtype you want. Maybe this would work:

```
private static Transport filterObjects(List<Transport> listOfTransport, Class clazz, int refNr) {
    List<Transport> transports = listOfTransport.stream().filter(clazz::isInstance).collect(Collectors.toList());
        
    return !transports.isEmpty() ? transports.get(refNr) : null;
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but it needs a lot of refactor works to get it works, becuase I need to pass the Class as argument overall. Thanks

Comment: You may also want to return an Optional instead of null

Comment: @user3122166 could you define "future proof" otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Just as you currently prioritize cars over planes, as your transport types grow you also need some kind of priority on which to return preferentially. You can solve this with an enum. You only need to expand your enum accordingly as soon as you add a new transport type. The enum could look something like:

```
enum Priority{
    Car(1), 
    Airplane(2);
    
    private int value;
    Priority (int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then you can refactor your method by grouping the elements of your list by their simple class names and adding them to a sorted map using the priority you define in your enum. You can then use the first entry of the map to determine the return value. Example:

```
private static Transport filterObjects(List<Transport> listOfTransport, int refNr) {
    Comparator<String> comp = Comparator.comparingInt(e -> Priority.valueOf(e).getValue());
    
    List<Transport> result = 
            listOfTransport.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                        e -> e.getClass().getSimpleName(), 
                                        () -> new TreeMap<>(comp), 
                                        Collectors.toList()))
                   .firstEntry().getValue();
     
     return (result != null && 0 <= refNr && refNr < result.size()) ? 
            result.get(refNr) : null;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First group the list elements into a map based on subtype, then create a list of subtypes of transport. Iterate this list and then check if corresponding entry exists in the map:

```java
private static final List<Class> subTypes = List.of(Cars.class, Airplanes.class);

private static Transport filterObjects(List<Transport> listOfTransport, int refNr) {
    Map<Class, List<Transport>> map = listOfTransport.stream()
                                                     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.getClass()));
    
    Optional<List<Transport>> op = subTypes.stream()
                                           .filter(map::containsKey)
                                           .findFirst();
    if(op.isPresent()) {
        return op.get().get(refNr); // This could cause IndexOutOfBoundsException
    }else{    
      return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do the following.

First, define your order:

```java
static final List<Class<? extends Transport>> ORDER = List.of(
    Car.class,
    Airplane.class
);
```

Then, you could write the following method:

```java
private static Transport filterObjects(List<Transport> listOfTransport, int refNr) {
    Map<Class<? extends Transport>, Transport> map = listOfTransport.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Transport::getClass, Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), list -> list.get(refNr))));

    return ORDER.stream()
        .filter(map::containsKey)
        .map(map::get)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
}
```

What this does, is mapping each distinct `Class` to the *`refNr`*th element which is a subtype of the respective class.

Then it walks over `ORDER` and checks if an element has been found within the original `listOfTransport`. The key won't exist in the map if `listOfTransport` does not contain any element of the particular class.

---

Note that if *any* element of a particular class exists in the map, the number of elements of that class is assumed to be at least `refNr`, otherwise an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown. With other words, each transport must occur 0 or at least `refNr` times within the `listOfTransport`.

Also note that `getClass()` does not necessarily yield the same result as `instanceof`. However, I have assumed here that each respective transport does not have further subclasses.